# When use footcite and footnote?

Tags: citing

I think it is used footcite to quote the author, and footnote is it quoted for the referecias?.

I need written the next text.

> See, Chang and Lin (2001) pag ? which ensures the theory of gravity

i using

```
\usepackage{natbib}


HELLO\footcite{[See], {chang2001}, [p. 30]}
HELLO\footnote{chang2001}

@article{chang2001,
  title={Training v-support vector classifiers: theory and algorithms},
  author={Chang, Chih-Chung and Lin, Chih-Jen},
  journal={Neural computation},
  volume={13},
  number={9},
  pages={2119--2147},
  year={2001},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
```

generated error:

[image]
I do not see the need to use footcite, 
my question is in which cases should be used

Comment: You have tagged your question `table-of-contents`, but it is evidently about citations and bibliographies. Am I right in thinking that you use `biblatex`? Also I must confess that I don't quite understand what you are asking. Can you reformulate your question, please?

Comment: `\footnote{chang2001}` would normally produce a footnote that just says "chang2001". `\footcite{chang2001}` would produce a footnote with the citation to `chang2001`. The exact form of that citation depends on the citation style you have chosen. `\footcite{[See], {chang2001}, [p. 30]}` would not work in any citation packages I work with, in `biblatex` `\footcite[See][30]{chang2001}` would produce a footnote with a citation to `chang2001` preceded by "See" and followed by "p. 30" (or whatever prefix for page your language requires).

Comment: @moewe i used pdflatex

Comment: Whether you use pdfLaTeX (or XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) is not particularly relevant. It is more relevant if you use `natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex` .... Maybe you can show us a short [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows us which bibliography package you use and how you want to use `\footcite` and `\footnote`. I still do not understand what you are asking. But that may well be a language barrier, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @moewe generate error with \footcite[See][30]{chang2001}

Comment: Unfortunately, these code snippets and the screenshot of your editor do *not* constitute an MWE. We will only be able to help you if you can show us a full MWE. Please see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). As I mentioned: Not all bibliography packages define `\footcite`. AFAIK only `biblatex` and `jurabib` define it. If you don't load those packages, you don't get to use `\footcite`.

Comment: @moewe i use natbib

Comment: Then you can't use `\footcite`. `natbib` does not define it. Where did you read about `\footcite`? Anyway, please make your example a proper MWE. I don't want to be the third person to downvote your question but you seem to consistently ignore my links to the MWE help page (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). So I'm getting a bit frustrated...

Comment: @moewe then how can I do it with natbib

Comment: @x-rw The code you've posted is still not a document that people can compile. (Even with an error.) If you simply want a citation in a footnote, then just use `\footnote{\textcite{chang2001}}`.  For a quick summary of `natbib` citation commands see [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793) or read the [`natbib` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/natbib).

Comment: @x-rw "then how can I do it with natbib" It would be helpful if you would tell us what "it" is? How should the output look like?

Comment: @samcarter i edited my question

Comment: @x-rw Should "See, chang2001 p.30 which ensures the theory of gravity" be in the text or at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @x-rw And do you really want to display your bib key and not something like "Chang and Lin (2001)"?

Comment: @samcarter 
yes it's okay, I'll modify my question, sorry

Comment: @samcarter but the pag 
will not show?

Comment: @x-rw I'm confused: Do you want to show the page number or not? You removed it in your last edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still have not answered my question if you want the citation within the text or at the bottom of the page, therefore this answer contains both possibilities.

I also had to guess things like your bibliography style, as your post does not contain a minimal working example ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{chang2001,
  title={Training v-support vector classifiers: theory and algorithms},
  author={Chang, Chih-Chung and Lin, Chih-Jen},
  journal={Neural computation},
  volume={13},
  number={9},
  pages={2119--2147},
  year={2001},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

text text text \citep[see][p. 30]{chang2001}

or 

text text text\footnote{see \citet{chang2001}, p. 30}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]